# Redireccionamiento con Nginx

Tags: nginx, digitalocean

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Nginx para un nuevo cliente. Estoy utilizando DigitalOcean como proveedor de una VM, en la misma tengo instalado Nginx y configurado correctamente con PHP. El problema viene al querer agregar la redirección 301 en el servidor de Nginx, ya que al agregar `return 301 $scheme://dominio.com$request_uri;` al momento de ir a la página en el explorador de internet me devuelve esto:

[image: Error de redireccionamiento]

No obstante, al retirar esta línea de la configuración del servidor, logro ingresar correctamente a la pagina sin ningún tipo de problema.

Lo que yo quiero realizar es una redirección del dominio `www` a uno sin el `www`.

Por otro lado, en la configuración de networking de digitalocean probé tanto teniendo el `www` como un campo CNAME como habiéndolo borrado, y de ninguna de las dos formas funciona, ¿alguien me podría indicar como realizar la configuración correctamente?

Adjunto el bloque de configuracion de mi servidor:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-$
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    root /var/www/domain.com/html/domain;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}
```

Por cuestiones de seguridad cambie el nombre de mi dominio por "domain.com"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que crear dos servidores `server` separados.

Leer la documentación [Converting Rewrite Rules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name domain.com; # Aquí va sin www

    # Resto de configuración
}
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta y debería ser aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta, implemente dichos cambios y funciona correctamente, no obstante en el momemto de pasar el test de nginx me dice que el puerto 443 esta duplicado, por lo tanto en el segundo bloque de server elimine la clausula de "default_server" y se soluciono todo.

Gracias chicos!